# Keep result of SPLIT() as string instead of number for VLOOKUP()

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, array-formulas

In Google Sheets, I have this formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA( VLOOKUP( SPLIT(F2,", "), A2:B8, 2, FALSE) )`

The intent is to take the comma-delimited string in cell `F2` and find all values associated with the pieces. This works correctly, except when one of the pieces of the string looks like a number. For example, if `F2` has the text `a, 1.2, 1.2.3` then VLOOKUP will look for `a` as a string, and for `1.2.3` as a string, but will look for `1.2` as a number.

How can I coerce the result of SPLIT so that each piece remains a string?

I have a public copy of a test spreadsheet viewable here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/115WmV0vfXfaRgT0fVifJo86od3irZQy5gB3l-g6c7Ts/edit?usp=sharing

---

As background information, VLOOKUP treats strings and numbers differently. For example, given this table (where the formulae are shown for the first column):

```
              A                    B
1           ="1.2"                STR
2           =1.2                  NUM
4  =VLOOKUP("1.2",A1:B2,2,0)
5  =VLOOKUP(1.2,A1:B2,2,0)
```

...the value shown in A4 will be "STR", and the value shown in A5 will be "NUM".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `CONCAT` a number with an empty string to convert it into its equivalent string representation.

`CONCAT(1.2,"")` yields `"1.2"`

To do this for every value, you must wrap the `CONCAT()` call in `ARRAYFORMULA()`:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(SPLIT(F2,", "),""))`

The final formula thus becomes:

`=TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(SPLIT(F2,", "),"")),A2:B8,2,FALSE)))`